# Адаптация под разрешение экранов

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Сделал схему зала через этот инструмент https://github.com/omahili/seatchart.js.

- Как можно его адаптировать под разрешение экрана?
- Или чтобы было что-то наподобие зума и тд как в canvas?

Comment: Нужно чтобы схема зала была в окошке и можно было туда сюда её двигать там, приближать и отдалять